# CodeIgniter: where to store static JSON file?

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I'm in a bit of a quandary as to where best to store a static JSON file in CodeIgniter. The file is to be read by a model (i.e. via PHP) and should not be publicly available in the browser.

I have tried to treat the file as, variously:

- a helper
- a config file
- a third-party file

...but CI expects all of those to contain PHP (in the case of the latter, a class.)

**Any suggestions on where I should store it?**

[NB: clearly I *could* store it in helpers and just load it manually, rather than `$this->load-helper()`, thus bypassing the attempted PHP interpretation, but that's a last resort.]

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what access you/php have outside the webroot. If you do, you could store it there and use the `directory_helper` in CI to read it. Also you could technically store the JSON as a variable in PHP.

If it is not very large, I would store it as a variable in a config like json.php and use it from there.

Comment: I'll look into the first option - thanks. Not keen on the second as it deserves to be its own file, rather than a PHP string.